# How can I install Filezilla on Linux 18.04 via command line?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu

How can I install Filezilla on Linux 18.04 via command line, kindly help.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'

wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt update

sudo apt install filezilla
```

while running sudo apt-get update i m getting this errors

```
Hit:8 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease        
Err:3 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu yakkety-getdeb InRelease                    
  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/adabbas/1stppa/ubuntu bionic Release            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-getdeb/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/programs-ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Target Translations (apps/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list:2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 7):

FileZilla is not installed by default, To install FileZilla on Ubuntu 18.04, Open the terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

**Connecting to the FTP server with FileZilla**

To connect to a FTP Server, Open the FileZilla FTP client and type the domain name or IP address of the FTP server in the Host field. Provide the FTP username and password and FTP port( you can leave the port empty if your server use default FTP port 21) and click on Quick connect button.

Comment: i had added the code please check above my question  and i am getting some error while applying above code

Comment: E: Unable to locate package filezilla this is the error

Comment: yes i did it but i am geting some error while running sudo apt-get update, please check above question, i had updated it

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend a clean installation from the repository 'universe' in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. You may have to remove everything that smells of 'xenial', 'yakkety' or any other previous version in order to keep 18.04 alias 'bionic' clean.

In an installed system 'universe' is already active, but in a live or persistent live system of standard Ubuntu, you must run

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

and after that you can install `filezilla` and many other program packages

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install filezilla
```

I tested now (in a persistent live Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) and it works. I get a working version of `filezilla`.